# Obtaining different solutions on solving a cplex model many times

Tags: python, python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I have an MIP model written with docplex and a solution pool written with cplex. My model has billions of solutions in reality. I need to solve this model several times (10 for example) with a certain populate number (10,000 for example) but I need the solutions of these multiple solves to be entirely different than each other. How can I achieve that with cplex? Is there a parameter or a approach for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a diversity filter for the solution pool, see [CPLEX > User's Manual for CPLEX > Discrete optimization > Solution pool: generating and keeping multiple solutions > Filtering the solution pool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/soln_pool/36_filter_title_synopsis.html) and also the reference documentation for the callable library function [CPXXaddsonpooldivfilter()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addsolnpooldivfilter.html) which explains in detail how the filter is evaluated. This can only be done if all your variables are binary.

Another option is to add a no-good cut for each solution you have already found.

Yet another option is to use an incumbent callback (or the generic callback with `CANDIDATE` context) to reject any solution that you already found.

All this being said, I am not clear why you want to solve the *same* model multiple times from scratch. Did you try to just continue the search? If the search stops due to a solution limit and you call it again, then it should continue where it previously stopped. So it should find different solutions.

Also, if you want to get thousands of solutions then I wonder what you do with those solutions. Maybe it can help to install or adjust an objective function that aims for certain solutions. Using different objective functions can only drive diversity of the solutions.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I need to solve a model multiple times because I have a part that changes one variable randomly and I need to change that variable in each solve. Without any adjustment, on each solve with different random variable I had some solutions but they where so much similar to each other.
How can I continue searching as you mentioned above?

Comment: (I need to change one constraint before continue searching)

Comment: You cannot continue the search if you modify the model.

Comment: How about adding a new solution and continue?Is that possibe?

Comment: What do you mean by "add a new solution"? Where do you want to add that? To the solution pool? That is not possible. You can add a new solution as MIP start. Or pretend that you already found that solution by adding a diversity filter that excludes this solution.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.**How about adding a new constraint and continue?

Comment: Like I said, after you modified the model, you cannot continue but must start from scratch. The only way to add a constraint "on the fly" is by adding a lazy constraint from a callback.